# How to make compiz works with Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, compiz, cube

Hi,

I've been installing Compiz since my first Ubuntu version (8.04). In each version, there are some issues, but each time I found a solution on the web.

This time, it seems that nobody encountered the same issue.

I'm running an Ubuntu 12.04. I installed `ccsm`, `compiz-fusion` and configured it for cube with cylinder for 4 screens in line and no column and `déformer les fenêtre` (in French version or Deform windows or something else).

The problems are the following:

- When I open a window on full screen, the window is misplaced (one half on a screen and the other on another). Moreover, when I click it for the first time, the window move instantly from the screen to an other area of the cube (the same screen or another)

  I tested to remove the "deform option" and it works properly, but I love this option, it's fun to see your window moving from left to right like *bubblegum*
- Compiz offers a way to open the 4 screens in the same time with `Alt+Ctrl+down` (in the French configuration by default) but when I try it my computer freezes and it's very sad.

**So my question is simple:** how to make it works?

My configuration: NVIDIA GeForce 310M with NVIDIA's drivers,
Ubuntu 12.04 (with Unity),
CCSM and  Compiz-Fusion

Bye !

Comment: Wobbly windows, is what you are looking for.

Comment: What are you talking about? `compiz` was installed by default in Ubuntu.

Comment: sounds to me like you have a driver issue there